# Show that for any real $x$,the Lebesgue measure of the set $\{ω ∈ (0, 1) : X(ω) ≤ x\}$ equals $F(x)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> Let $F$ be a probability distribution function on $\Bbb R$. For each $ω∈(0,1)$ , define $X(ω)=\inf\{x∈R:F(x)>ω\}$.
>
> (a) Show that $X$ defines a real-valued function on $(0, 1)$, which is non-decreasing and hence measurable with respect to the Borel σ-field on $(0, 1)$.
>
> (b) Show that for any real $x$,the Lebesgue measure of the set $\{ω ∈ (0, 1) : X(ω) ≤ x\}$ equals $F(x)$.
>
> (c) Taking $Ω=(0,1)$, $A = \beta(0, 1)$ and $P$ = Lebesgue measure on $(0,1)$, conclude that,given any probability distribution function $F$ on $\Bbb R$, we have a random variable $X$ on $(Ω, A, P)$, whose distribution function is $F$ .

My attempt:

I did part (a) as a routine computation.

(b) $\lambda\{\omega \in (0,1):X(\omega) \le x\}=\text{inf }\mu(A \supseteq \{\omega \in (0,1):X(\omega) \le x\})$ $$=\text{inf }\mu(A \supseteq \{\omega \in (0,1):\inf \{z \in \Bbb R: F(z) > \omega\}  \le x\})$$

> How to simplify this to obtain $F(x)$ ?

(c) It's apparent that doing part (a) and (b) gives us the construction for $X$ on $(Ω, A, P)$, whose distribution function is $F$ .

Thanks in Advance for help!

Comment: Things would be easier if $F(x)>\omega$ would instead have been $F(x)\geq\omega$. It is true for both, but the second is easyer to prove.

Answer (score 1):

For $\omega\in\left(0,1\right)$ let $Y\left(\omega\right):=\inf\left(\left\{ x\in\mathbb{R}\mid F\left(x\right)\geq\omega\right\} \right)$.

On base of this it is immediate that $F\left(x\right)\geq\omega\implies x\geq Y\left(\omega\right)$.

Fortunately the opposite direction is also true.

This because we have $F\left(x\right)\geq\omega$ for every $x>Y\left(\omega\right)$
so that the fact that $F$ is right- continuous implies that also
$F\left(Y\left(\omega\right)\right)\geq\omega$.

So for every $\omega\in\left(0,1\right)$ and every $x\in\mathbb{R}$
we have: $$F\left(x\right)\geq\omega\iff x\geq Y\left(\omega\right)\tag1$$

From $\left(1\right)$ it follows that: $$\lambda\left(\left\{ \omega\in\left(0,1\right)\mid Y\left(\omega\right)\leq x\right\} \right)=\lambda\left(\left\{ \omega\in\left(0,1\right)\mid\omega\leq F\left(x\right)\right\} \right)=\lambda\left(\left(0,F\left(x\right)\right]\right)=F\left(x\right)\tag2$$

But we were asked to prove that for $X$, so we are not ready yet.

Now observe that $Y\leq X$ because $\left\{ x\in\mathbb{R}\mid F\left(x\right)>\omega\right\} \subseteq\left\{ x\in\mathbb{R}\mid F\left(x\right)\geq\omega\right\} $.

Consequently $\left\{ \omega\in\left(0,1\right)\mid X\left(\omega\right)\leq x\right\} \subseteq\left\{ \omega\in\left(0,1\right)\mid Y\left(\omega\right)\leq x\right\} $
for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now for some $\omega\in\left(0,1\right)$ let it be that $X\left(\omega\right)>x$
and $Y\left(\omega\right)\leq x$.

Here $X\left(\omega\right)>x$ implies that $F\left(x\right)\leq\omega$,
and $Y\left(\omega\right)\leq x$ implies that $F\left(x\right)\geq\omega$.

Then $\omega=F\left(x\right)$.

Conversely we also have $F(x)\in\left\{ \omega\in\left(0,1\right)\mid Y\left(\omega\right)\leq x\right\}$ on base of $(1)$ and proved is now that: $$\left\{ \omega\in\left(0,1\right)\mid Y\left(\omega\right)\leq x\right\} =\left\{ F\left(x\right)\right\} \cup\left\{ \omega\in\left(0,1\right)\mid X\left(\omega\right)\leq x\right\}\tag3$$

Then based on $(2), (3)$ and the fact that singleton $\{F(x)\}$ has measure $0$ we conclude that:$$\lambda\left(\left\{ \omega\in\left(0,1\right)\mid X\left(\omega\right)\leq x\right\} \right)=F\left(x\right)\tag4$$

Comment: c) If $U\sim Uniforme(0,1)$ then $X(U)\sim F$.

Comment: @DanielCamarenaPerez Yes, that is correct. Also $Y(U)$ has CDF $F$.